# Relocate WAS Liberty servers

Tags: websphere-liberty

Ok, this seems like it ought to be obvious.....

Suppose I don't want to have my servers under ${WLP_HOME}/usr/servers.
How do I make WLP create and manage them elsewhere?  The InfoCenter is mysteriously silent.  I've been sorting through the files in WLP, but nothing pops out yet.

This is in the context of a production environment, not like on a developer system.  WAS full profile can let you define where a whole node profile will reside.  Looking for the WLP analog to that.

Answer (score 2):

The information is in the ${WLP_HOME}/README.TXT

You can try WLP_USER_DIR environment variable.

"The WLP_USER_DIR environment variable can be used to specify an alternate
location for ${wlp.user.dir}. If this is specified, the runtime will look for
shared resources and server definitions in the specified directory."

Answer (score 2):

It is buried a bit but, it is described in the knowledge center [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html)

It suggests setting WLP_USER_DIR IN the ${wlp.install.dir}/etc/server.env properties file